# Margin/padding hover with pseudo element issue

Tags: html, css

I created four boxes, and when one of the boxes are clicked or selected an hovered on, it creates extra padding or margin that overlaps the other boxes.

I have tried doing:

```
.marketing-service.active {
   margin: 0;
}
```

and

```
.marketing-service.active:hover {
   margin: 0;
}
```

But both were failed attempts. When viewing the snippet or [Jsfddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eujyz3r3/) be sure at least one box is on the second row and click on the first box, then hover over it.

What can I do to get the all of the boxes to stay in their original location, but remove the extra spacing the down arrow is causing?

```js
$('#marketing-tab1').addClass('active');
 $('#marketing1').show();
  
  $('.marketing-service').click(function() {
  $('.marketing-service.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  
  //To get the service display box to show
  var item_number = $(this).attr('id').replace('marketing-tab', '');
  /* $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#service-display-box").offset().top
   }, 1500);*/
  $('#marketing'+item_number).show().siblings('.marketing-service-section').hide();
 });
```

```css
#marketing-services {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
}

.marketing-service {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marketing-service:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.marketing-service:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.marketing-service:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
  z-index: 1;
}

.marketing-service-wrap {
  padding: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}

.marketing-service-title {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.marketing-img {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}


/*-- Down Arrow for boxes --*/

.marketing-service.active,
#marketing-tab1.active {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
}

.marketing-service.active:after,
.marketing-service.active:before,
#marketing-tab1.active:after,
#marketing-tab1.active:before {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.marketing-service.active:after,
#marketing-tab1.active:after {
  border-width: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.marketing-service.active:before,
#marketing-tab1.active:before {
  border-color: #FFF;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
  border-width: 36px;
  margin-left: -36px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="marketing-services">
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab1">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">A</h2>
      <img src="../images/marketing-seo.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab2">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">B</h2>
      <img src="../images/marketing-ppc.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab3">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">C</h2>
      <img src="../images/marketing-conversion.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab4">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">D</h2>
      <img src="../images/marketing-email.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so you want to remove the white space around the arrow but want the arrow to appear?

Comment: @kittyCat Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `border-color:fff`. edit this in your css:

```
.marketing-service.active:before,
#marketing-tab1.active:before {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
  border-width: 36px;
  margin-left: -36px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Here's the working snippet:

```js
$('#marketing-tab1').addClass('active');
 $('#marketing1').show();
  
  $('.marketing-service').click(function() {
  $('.marketing-service.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  
  //To get the service display box to show
  var item_number = $(this).attr('id').replace('marketing-tab', '');
  /* $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#service-display-box").offset().top
   }, 1500);*/
  $('#marketing'+item_number).show().siblings('.marketing-service-section').hide();
 });
```

```css
#marketing-services {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
}

.marketing-service {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marketing-service:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.marketing-service:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.marketing-service:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
  z-index: 1;
}

.marketing-service-wrap {
  padding: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}

.marketing-service-title {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.marketing-img {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}


/*-- Down Arrow for boxes --*/

.marketing-service.active,
#marketing-tab1.active {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
}

.marketing-service.active:after,
.marketing-service.active:before,
#marketing-tab1.active:after,
#marketing-tab1.active:before {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.marketing-service.active:after,
#marketing-tab1.active:after {
  border-width: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.marketing-service.active:before,
#marketing-tab1.active:before {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
  border-width: 36px;
  margin-left: -36px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="marketing-services">
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab1">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">A</h2>
      <img src="../images/marketing-seo.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab2">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">B</h2>
      <img src="../images/marketing-ppc.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab3">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">C</h2>
      <img src="../images/marketing-conversion.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab4">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">D</h2>
      <img src="../images/marketing-email.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow such a simple over-look. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ Paul, I edited my answer, in case if last version of my answer was not working fine, try the new one. Also please don't forget to accept the answer.